# How to sort a MultiKeyMap in java

Tags: java, multimap

I have some code like this. I want to sort this multikeymap according to values. My multikeymap has (key1, key2, value).

```
MultiKeyMap multiKeyMap = new MultiKeyMap();
multiKeyMap.put("New York","IBM",10);
multiKeyMap.put("Sydney","Infosys",3);
multiKeyMap.put("Prague","JP Morgan",14);
multiKeyMap.put("Scotland","RBS",23);
multiKeyMap.put("Paris","Nomura",124);
multiKeyMap.put("Melbourne","Citi Bank",24);
multiKeyMap.put("Aukland","Bank of America",3);
```

Comment: what is the key in your example ?

Comment: The first two are keys and they are strings

Comment: imagine you add ("New York","IBM",10) and ("London","IBM",11) - which value are you expecting to retrieve querying for IBM ? Is it 10 or is it 11 ?

Comment: I don't think if we can retrieve using IBM. In multikeymap, one need to use multiKeyMap.get("New York","IBM") to retrieve values. Using just "IBM" will return error. I have tried and i get error.